How to place and draw elements at specific coordinates using Java with Structurizr
I am using Structurizr java for our enterprise application. For placing or drawing an element at specific co-ordinates, I have tried using ElementView in Manual Layout. But its not helping to place an element at a position.
Please suggest me a way to order the elements through java
I have followed the below way:
ElementView eleView = deploymentView.getElements().stream()
    .filter(ev -> ev.getElement().getName().equals("nodeName")).findFirst().orElse(null);

if (eleView != null) {
    eleView.setX(30);
    eleView.setY(40);
}


This worked for me when I did setMergeFromRemote(false) on WorkspaceApiClient instance to force push our layout information.
